# Can we assume black hole is just two big stars revolving around each other?

Tags: black-holes

I am just curious by watching all the black hole theories.I think every phenomenon of the black hole can be explained just by this theory that

Black hole is just some bunch of stars(possibly BIG stars) revolving around each other creating a state which is described as a black hole.

Can someone tell me how this theory can be wrong?

Comment: Why wouldn't light from these stars be visible?

Comment: I am extremely sorry, i phrased it incorrectly. I intended to refer the object or space between the revolving stars as black hole. In most of the materials available to novice, it is presented as object with extremely high density.

Answer (score 4):

Look at [these animations](http://www.galacticcenter.astro.ucla.edu/animations.html) of the galactic center. You can see the stars orbiting some central object, but the central object is not a star, because it is not visible. But it is obviously very massive, because the other stars are orbiting it witout causing any wobbles on it. Our understanding is that the central object is a supermassive black hole.

It is not possible to explain the central object as a group of stars, because we would see them in the telescopes. But what we see are only the other stars that are orbiting something invisible.

Comment: Love that video. There really is no way to watch it and say "No, those stars aren't orbiting a massive body that doesn't emit light"

Comment: I am extremely sorry, i phrased it incorrectly. I intended to refer the object or space between the revolving stars as black hole. In most of the materials available to novice, it is presented as object with extremely high density.

Answer (score 3):

Black holes are inferred through the confluence of two things.

First, some observations are made of a dynamical phenomenon which tells us that there is a certain amount of mass present in a system and that this mass must be concentrated into a relatively small region. Usually, the limits on this region are *far* bigger than the Schwarzschild radius for a black hole of that mass. i.e. We cannot tell from the observations that the mass is concentrated enough to be a black hole.

The second thing is to discount the alternatives. So your question supposes that rather than a black hole, the mass could be due to some (many?) large stars that are bound together in some way. But large stars are incredibly luminous. A necessary condition to suppose that some candidate object is a black hole is that it is not emitting the light you would expect from any other object or collection of objects with the same mass.

Answer (score 2):

I just want to add to the answers that for some time it was believed (maybe considered is a better word), that galactic centers were actually stars. It was believed that the Milky Way center could be a very compact cluster of stars to dim to see them, or a collection of very heavy giant stars called warmers. So yes, your theory was seriously considered for years during the last century.

It was finally ruled out by the facts presented in the other answers, mainly by the observation of very fast and small orbits of the stars around the center of the Milky Way, and the fact that there is no emission (there is actually a dim middle infrarred emission with a variation, thought to be mass falling inside the black hole, and emmiting as it accelerates).

Comment: Downvote why? Nothing I said was wrong, it was a completion to the answers.